# MinGW: reading binary data fail

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a binary file on Windows 7 with a program compiled by MinGW. The binary file is ~10M in size but my program can only read less than 1000 bytes and it thinks it reached EOF.

Here is the code. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but I just can't seem to find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TS_FILE "foo.data"

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int r;
    unsigned char buf[1024];

    fd = open(TS_FILE, O_RDONLY|O_BINARY);
    printf("fd: %d\n", fd);

    if ( fd == -1 )
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        r = read(fd, buf, 1000);
        if ( r != 1000 )
        {
            printf("read error. %d\n", r);
            perror("read");
        }

        if ( r == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

The program will say it reads 736 bytes and that's the EOF.

Could somebody tell me what is going on? Thanks!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your program is indeed reading the entire file. It reads the file 1000 bytes at a time until there are, in this case, 736 bytes left. Then it reads those final 736 bytes and `read` returns `736`. You are mistakenly treating the inability to read the full 1000 bytes as an error, but it is not an error. If `read` fails then the error condition is marked by the return value being -1.

Your loop should perhaps be more like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    r = read(fd, buf, 1000);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        printf("read error\n");
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (r != 1000)
    {
        //entire file has been read
        break;
    }
}
close(fd);
```

A couple of other points:

1. The correct type for `r` is `size_t`.
2. Rather than hardcoding `1024` and `1000`, you would be better with something like `#define BUFFLEN 1024` so that you don't keep repeating those magic values.